# Get the value form dropdown using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following jquery function for get the drop down value in a table row.But its not give the value.

HTML

```
<select id='statusprocess'><option value='optSelected'>Selected</option><option value='optNotSelected'>Not Selected</option></select>
```

JQUERY

```
     var select = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="select"]').map(function () {
                    return this.text();
                }).get();
```

How to find the dropdown and get selected option text?

**Answer Is:**

This is the Exact way to find the dropdown in Table and get selected the Selected Text.

```
var select = $(this).closest('tr').find('select option:selected').text();
```

It was Working Fine Now.

Comment: would be great if you can share html too

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').find('select')`, there's no `input[type="select"]`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the ID already, why don't you just get it via the ID?

```
$("#statusprocess").val();
```

The above statement returns 'optSelected' or 'optNotSelected'.

Or else if you were referring to the "option text" instead of the "option value", you can try this.

```
$("#statusprocess :selected").text();
```

The statement above returns 'Selected' or 'Not Selected'.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no input[type=select] exist.**

Your `dropdown list` is a `<select>` element, not an `<input type="select" />`. So you should use the `select` instead of using `input[type = "select"]`.

Selected option value:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('#statusprocess').val();
```

Selected option text:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('#statusprocess option:selected').text();
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9SdQh/)

OR if you have single dropdown inside the `tr`, you can also use element selector (i.e `select`) this:

Selected option value:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();
```

Selected option text:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('select option:selected').text();
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9SdQh/4/)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can simply get it by

```
$("#statusprocess").val()
```

---

HTML

```
<select id='statusprocess' onChange="getIt()"><option value='optSelected'>Selected</option><option value='optNotSelected'>Not Selected</option></select>
```

SCRIPT

```
function getIt(){
var i=$("#statusprocess").val()
alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value of dropdown when the value `changes`.  so use `change` method to get the value when `option` changes. [JQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$('input[type="select"]').change(function(){

var value = $( "select option:selected" ).text();
});
```

**Update**

you can just fetch the value by using the class also.

```
$(".selectboxClass").on('change',function(){
var value = $( ".selectboxClass option:selected" ).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to get, you can either get the value:

```
$("#statusprocess").val();
```

or the text of the selected

```
$("#statusprocess option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Exact way to find the dropdown in Table and get selected the Selected Text.

```
var select = $(this).closest('tr').find('select option:selected').text();
```

It was Working Fine Now.